# Aligning children widgets under Stack Widget properly

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to ask how do I properly align the widgets under the stack, I am still confused using the `Position` Widget and so I am just using Container for my Text Widget.
[Here is the image output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tnr0X.png), the `Name` is at the top, I wanted to position it under the circular image(*check the red texts, that's how I wanted it to be positioned*) and so on

Here is my source code for the sample image above..

```
return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.black,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
              width: double.infinity,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 10, right: 5),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Container(),
                  Container(
                    width: 28,
                    height: 28,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey.shade200, // border color
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    ),
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1), // border width
                      child: Container(
                        // or ClipRRect if you need to clip the content
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          color: Colors.white
                              .withOpacity(0.25), // inner circle color
                        ),
                        child: InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => const SecondPage()),
                              );
                            },
                            child: const Icon(
                                EvaIcons.settings_2_outline)), // inner content
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 53.5,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
                  child: const CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 50,
                    backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                        'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1552058544-f2b08422138a?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=699&q=80'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const Center(
              child: Text(
                "Name",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      )),
    );
```

I would appreciate any help with an explanation as well how it should be achieved, I am just really confused with the Stack Widget now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i would do is

1. center align the stack
2. put the image and the name text in a column
3. change the padding for the settings icon to a Positioned with the same properties.

so the code will look something like this:

```
return   Scaffold(
            extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
            body: SafeArea(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.center, //<----- align the stack center
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                    width: double.infinity,
                  ),
                  Positioned(//<---- Change padding to postioned
                    top: 15,
                    left: 10,
                    right: 5,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Container(),
                        Container(
                          width: 28,
                          height: 28,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.grey.shade200, // border color
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          ),
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1), // border width
                            child: Container(
                              // or ClipRRect if you need to clip the content
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                color: Colors.white
                                    .withOpacity(0.25), // inner circle color
                              ),
                              child: InkWell(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) => const SecondPage()),
                                    );
                                  },
                                  child: const Icon(EvaIcons
                                      .settings_2_outline)), // inner content
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Column(
                      //<------Put image and text in Column
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 53.5,
                            backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
                            child: const CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 50,
                              backgroundImage: CachedNetworkImageProvider(
                                  'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1552058544-f2b08422138a?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=699&q=80'),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const Text(
                          "Name",
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )),
          );
```

Comment: Hello it worked! Thanks, I think I might play with the ``Positioned`` Widget, I heavily rely on ``Padding`` since it is my go-to.. It is my first time seeing ``Align`` Widget as well, does this only work under the ``Stack``? Anway, thank you it worked, I'll just play around with it!

Comment: glad to help. Positioned is a very powerful widget in a stack and would 100% recommend using it in a stack. the Align widget too, tho it is not as custom as padding or Positioned but it is a helpful widget